# Python type hints: `def f(e: Union[np, tf])` for `import numpy as np`?

Tags: python, types, type-parameter, python-typing, pep585

Goal: restrict function argument to only accept the `numpy` or `tensorflow` module.

Some ideas I have, use [`Literal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Literal) types ([PEP586](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0586)):

```
Literal["np", "tf"]
```

Then use [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?#globals) to find the symbol. This would work reasonably well, though obviously skips the module type check.

Is there some way I can accept either the str representation or the module itself? - Passing in the module itself gave this error:

> Expected type `Literal["np", "tf"]`, got `Union[__init__.py, __init__.py]` instead

But I don't know how to create `Union[__init__.py, __init__.py]`, e.g., this doesn't work:

```
Union[Union[__init__.py, __init__.py], Literal["np", "tf"]]
```

Comment: For starters, Literal types can only be parameterized with literal ints, byte and unicode strings, bools, Enum values and None. So you *could* use a string, I suppose, but that isn't really great since you'll lose most type information with the dynamic `globals()` look up anyway... and I don't think you can type hint a module, well, you can, probably use `types.ModuleType` but that won't really give you much, if you expect it to type check the attributes of the module

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - So is what I'm trying to do impossible then?

Comment: why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use type checking? You could assert like so

`assert module == np or module == tf, f"{module.__name__} not numpy or tensorflow"`

Comment: They are asking for type hints.

Comment: @Evan - yeah would be great to have this AOT.